# I have a question about NSCollectionLayoutGroup initializers

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am creating a CompositionalLayout.
I have a question about using NSCollectionLayoutGroup initializer.

The creating layouts code is as follows.

```
func generateSharedAlbumsLayout() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(140), heightDimension: .absolute(186))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)
//    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
    
    let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(44))
    let sectionHeader = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: AlbumsViewController.sectionHeaderElementKind, alignment: .top)
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [sectionHeader]
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging
    
    return section
}
```

What is the difference between the following?
first, use subitem, count initializer.

```
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)
```

[image]

second, use subitems initializer.

```
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
```

[image]

The first result is my expectation, but second is not.
What's the reason?

I have another question.
I think this layout is horizontal, but why does it use vertical?
If I use horizontal initializer, the result is wrong as follows.

```
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)
```

[image]

Thank you for reading it.
I'm looking forward to your response.

Comment: I knew why the height of the cell was decreasing. This is because the height Dimension of the item is `.fractionalWidth(1.0)`. Then in this situation using `let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)`, why is the height of the cell increasing? And, why use vertical?

Comment: https://nemecek.be/blog/66/detailed-look-at-the-nscollectionlayoutgroup